# Android Build failure : Could not get unknown property 'assembleDebug' for project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-gradle-3.1.0

I need to create Jar and copy to lib folder, which is done in following task :

```
task copyJarToLib(type: Copy, dependsOn: 'createJar') {
    from "build/libs/lib1.jar"
    from "build/libs/lib2.jar"
    into "../App/libs/"
}
```

I have to execute this after apk generation. So, I am calling following instruction at the end of the module-app build.gradle :

```
assembleDebug.finalizedBy(copyJarToLib)
```

Issue is observed after upgrading the gradle plugin to 3.1.0 and gradle to 4.4.
Same implementation is working fine with gradle 2.3.

Comment: Try Invalid Caches/ Restart in the file menu.

Comment: @AarthTandel : I have tried Invalid caches/ restart already. Didnt work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute something at the end of build, you can do it as follows:

```
gradle.buildFinished {

    copy {
        from "build/libs/lib1.jar"
        from "build/libs/lib2.jar"
        into "../App/libs/"
    }
}
```

If you want to execute task before apk is built the you can:

```
afterEvaluate {
    project.tasks.findByName('preDebugBuild').dependsOn(':<module>:copyJarToLib')
}
```

Comment: @Vinodh did you get any error or the behavior is not expected?

Comment: buildFinished is executed after the compilation failure. Compile time issue is observed as libs are not copied .

Comment: @Vinodh so you want something which will be executed before apk is built?

Answer (score 0):

base on Android Studio 2020.3.1, you can use follow codes

```
afterEvaluate {
    project.tasks.findByName('preDebugBuild').dependsOn(copyJarToLib)
}
```